Request with express hangs
I have the following code:
export default class Server {
  private app: Express;
  public port: number = 3000;

  constructor() {
    if (!isNode) {
      throw new Error("The server must be initialized on the server side");
    }

    this.app = express();
  }

  public init() {
    this.port = this.port++;
    if (this.port > 3050) {
      console.warn(
        "The server has already tried to start on 50 different ports. It is reccomended to open a port in the range of 3000 to 3050 for the best performance."
      );
    }

    if (this.port > 3100) {
      throw new Error(
        "Attempted to start the server on 100 different ports. None were open, aborting."
      );
    }

    try {
      this.app.listen(this.port++);
      this.api();
    } catch (err: any) {
      if (err.code === "EADDRINUSE") {
        this.init();
      }

      throw err;
    }
  }

    private async api() {
    console.log("api called");

    const catMethods = {
      GET: [
        "access",
        "lstat",
        "stat",
        "statfs",
        "readFile",
        "readdir",
        "readlink",
        "realpath",
        "watch",
        "opendir",
        "glob",
        "constants"
      ],
      PUT: [
        "chmod",
        "chown",
        "lchmod",
        "lchown",
        "utimes",
        "lutimes",
        "truncate",
        "writeFile",
        "appendFile"
      ],
      POST: ["mkdir", "mkdtemp", "open", "symlink", "link", "copyFile", "cp"],
      DELETE: ["rmdir", "unlink", "rename"]
    };

    const fsMethod = (
      // @ts-ignore
      // Just copying types from express
      req: Request<{}, any, any, QueryString.ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>,
      // @ts-ignore
      // Just copying types from express
      res: Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>,
      catMethod: string[]
    ) => {
      console.log("fs method called");
      if (
        typeof req.headers.method !== "string" ||
        typeof req.headers.args !== "string"
      ) {
        return res
          .status(422)
          .json({success: false, error: "Invalid header encoding not found"});
      }

      const method = req.headers.method;
      if (!method) {
        return res
          .status(422)
          .json({success: false, error: "Method not found"});
      }

      console.log("obtained headers");

      const args = JSON.parse(req.headers.args || "[]");
      let matchedMethod = false;

      for (let i = 0; i < catMethod.length; i++) {
        if (method === catMethod[i]) {
          matchedMethod = true;
        }
      }

      if (!matchedMethod) {
        return res
          .status(405)
          .json({success: false, error: "Method not allowed"});
      }

      console.log("found match");

      try {
        this.method(method, args);
        console.log("ran method");
      } catch (err: any) {
        return res.status(500).json({success: false, error: err});
      }

      console.log("finished api");
    };

    this.app.get("/fs", async (req, res) => {
      console.log("get");
      fsMethod(req, res, catMethods.GET);
    });

    this.app.post("/fs", async (req, res) => {
      fsMethod(req, res, catMethods.POST);
    });

    this.app.put("/fs", async (req, res) => {
      fsMethod(req, res, catMethods.PUT);
    });

    this.app.delete("/fs", async (req, res) => {
      fsMethod(req, res, catMethods.DELETE);
    });
  }
}

const server = new Server();
server.init();
console.log("server started");

This code creates an api for different methods. Here is an example thunder client request:

However, when I run the request it hangs on the processing screen in Thunder client.
Here is the order of the console logs:
# Before request
api called
server started

# After
get
fs method called
obtained headers
found match
ran method
finished api 

I tried using postman and I still get the same result. I'm using macos 14 sonoma. Where am I going wrong?

Where is the code for this.method()?  That's where the request has to be handled and a response sent back to the client.  Express does NOT automatically send a response.  You HAVE to send one or the request just "hangs" and may eventually will timeout.

You probably need to send back a success response instead of basically leaving the client on read.
try {
    this.method(method, args);
    console.log("ran method");
    return res.status(200); // blank 200 OK response
} catch (err: any) {
    return res.status(500).json({success: false, error: err});
}


I believe if no response is returned express will automatically send a 200 status code. Any way this still isn't working.

It looks like you have a few bugs in your code. The problem lays with the arguments being passed and the condition used within the for loop, and last the 405 response. Will outline each below:
Arguments being passed. passing a string array.
this.app.get("/fs", async (req, res) => {
      console.log("get");
      fsMethod(req, res, catMethods.GET);
    });

    this.app.post("/fs", async (req, res) => {
      fsMethod(req, res, catMethods.POST);
    });

    this.app.put("/fs", async (req, res) => {
      fsMethod(req, res, catMethods.PUT);
    });

    this.app.delete("/fs", async (req, res) => {
      fsMethod(req, res, catMethods.DELETE);
    });

const method = req.headers.method; // will always have a value
The REST method would never match because your comparing to an element within the array list.
for (let i = 0; i < catMethod.length; i++) {
  if (method === catMethod[i]) { // ex. 'GET' != element within list
     matchedMethod = true;
  }
}

Lastly, the following response is also invalid please review resource below this post for more info.
   if (!matchedMethod) {
        return res // requires resetting headers with list of "allowable" REST methods.
          .status(405)
          .json({success: false, error: "Method not allowed"});
      }

SOLUTION:
const method = req.headers.method.toUpperCase();
fsMethod(req, res, catMethods[method]);

the above implementation should work but, just incase you are using typescript and see a type error
const method = req.headers.method.toUpperCase();
fsMethod(req, res, (catMethods as Record<string, string[]>)[method]);
// or 
fsMethod(req, res, (catMethods as Record<string, any>)[method]);
// or
fsMethod(req, res, (catMethods as any)[method]); 

...
// you would then delete the for loop
let matchedMethod = false;

for (let i = 0; i < catMethod.length; i++) {
    if (method === catMethod[i]) {
      matchedMethod = true;
   }
 }
... And then update the condition to validate the incoming request method previously mentioned and update response headers
if (!catMethod) {

    const allowedMethods = ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELTE']; // may not need if catMethods defined in global scope within class
    // for example: const allowedMethods = Object.keys(catMethods)
    res.set('Allow', allowedMethods.join(', '));
    return res
      .status(405)
      .json({success: false, error: "Method not found"});
}


Though, honestly securing routes this way seems unnecessary considering that the resource would only run if its being processed with the correct method upon request.
Hope I was able to help.
Resource:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405


It turns out express hangs unless you send a response with content. So I just my try/catch block to:
 try {
    return res
       .status(200)
       .json({success: true, data: this.method(method, args)});
} catch (err: any) {
   return res.status(500).json({success: false, error: err});
}

